# Vector of templates -> use member of child class

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I want to create a vector of template items

My approach is :

```
class InterfaceItem
{
}

template <typename T>
class Item : public InterfaceItem
{
 T value;
 T GetValue();
}

std::vector<InterfaceItem*> items;
items.push_back(new Item<int>());
```

This approach works so far, but now i have the Problem to access my value of items. What is the best approach for that?

I thought about saving the type of the child in the base class and then a cast to this child class, but then i can only us default or known types.

What is your approach to get

```
auto value = items[0].GetValue(); // will not compile
```

Comment: You seem to have completely misunderstood the purpose of inheritance. Your `InterfaceItem` should provide an interface, as the name suggests.

Comment: You will need to cast the `InterfaceItem*` to its derived type before accessing members of the derived type.

Comment: @HappyCoder He should not have to do that and fix his design instead.

Comment: Yeah that is the correct approach. I was just stating the correct way to access derived type members.

Comment: This question is missing one important bit. Do you intend to store only single type items (`int` in this case), or multiple types of items in the **same** vector?

Comment: If you really intend to access a special attribute of `item` then you should use `std::vector<Item*> items;`. Otherwise (the general case) put access methods in your Interface named `InterfaceItem`

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I wasn't happy with this design to, so i have to reconsider it. What is your favourite design to store Items with different template values ?

Comment: I want so store multiple types of items in the same vector otherwise it isn't any problem

Comment: (On behalf of @John Paine): "It wont compile because your InterfaceItem class doesn't have such interface that you're requesting. You can make InterfaceItem a template class and get values from it."

Comment: @Hunk Can you enumerate all the types you might store in this vector?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem to access my value of items. What is the best approach for that?

The typical design that is used with inheritance is to access the values through the interface. To access something through an interface, it must have a member function. And in order to get polymorphic behaviour from the interface, the member function should be virtual. And, since the interface itself cannot implement the member function, and any derived class probably should, it should be a pure virtual member function. Also, don't forget to have a virtual destructor if you intend to store the derived objects using a base pointer. Here is an example:

```
class InterfaceItem {
    virtual int GetValue() = 0;
    virtual ~InterfaceItem();
};

class Item: public InterfaceItem {
    int GetValue() override;
}
```

Now, this will work:

```
auto value = items[0]->GetValue();
```

Notice that the interface function is not templated. Compile time polymorphism (templates) and run time polymorphism (inheritance) don't always mix well. You cannot override a template function. Typically, you'll have to choose which type of polymorphism you will use.

Comment: OP said added that vector may contain multiple types of items. So this approach doesn't work, as `GetValue` is now hardcoded to `int`. (But he/she probably misunderstood how `auto` works).

Comment: @user694733 well, OP can assign the pointers in the vector to different types that derive `InterfaceItem` just fine. But if they want to get different types from `GetValue`, then what they want makes little sense in a statically typed language. They're trying to re-implement Boost.Any or Boost.Variant, but without knowing what they need it for, I suspect that what they have is a XY-problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inheritance in this case. Simply do:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Item {
    T value;
    T GetValue(){return value;}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Item<int>*> items;
    items.push_back(new Item<int>());
    auto value = items[0]->GetValue(); // will compile
}
```

Don't forget to delete the items, or use a vector of `std::unique_ptr<>`

Answer (score 0):

You could do some kind of visitor pattern.

First, make a base visitor class which can visit all the types you're going to use:

```
class ItemVisitor {
public:
     virtual void visit (int a) = 0;
     virtual void visit (std::string a) = 0;
     virtual void visit (double a) = 0;
};
```

Then make your `InterfaceItem` accept `ItemVisitor`s:

```
class InterfaceItem
{
public:
    virtual void accept(ItemVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};
```

Now instead of using `GetValue`, call `visit` on the visitor inside `Item`:

```
template <typename T>
class Item : public InterfaceItem
{
public:
    Item (T t) : value{std::move(t)} {}
    void accept(ItemVisitor& visitor) override { visitor.visit(value); }

private:
    T value;
};
```

Now when you want to access your items, write a visitor to do all the work:

```
class PrintVisitor : public ItemVisitor {
    void visit (int a) override { std::cout << "int " << a << '\n'; }
    void visit (std::string a) override { std::cout << "std::string " << a << '\n'; }
    void visit (double a) override { std::cout << "double " << a << '\n'; } 
};
```

Then make an instance of your visitor and use that to access the elements with their erased type:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<InterfaceItem*> items;
    items.push_back(new Item<int>(42));
    items.push_back(new Item<std::string>("Hi there"));
    items.push_back(new Item<double>(42.12));
    items.push_back(new Item<int>(24));

    PrintVisitor visitor{};

    for (auto i : items) {
        i->accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

This will call the correct overload of `visit` inside `PrintVisitor` for each item.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06aca81054305e78)

Note that you should use `std::unique_ptr` rather than raw pointers for your vector.